# Rename file names incrementally

Tags: windows, powershell, file-rename, batch-rename

I would like to rename file names in a folder incrementally by prefixing a string. I have found this Windows PowerShell script which only prefixes a string:

```
cd C:\Users\strz\Desktop\Data_zMob\processed_\PROD_3Euro_OK\Z_586_20160307_0850
$files=get-childitem
foreach ($file in $files) {
Rename-Item $file.name ("stringToAppend" + $file.name)
}
```

I am not familiar with this scripting language at all. So I tried this:

```
    cd C:\Users\strz\Desktop\Data_zMob\processed_\PROD_3Euro_OK\Z_586_20160307_0850
    $files=get-childitem
    $lotId=1
    foreach ($file in $files) {
    Rename-Item $file.name ($lotId + $file.name)
    $lotId++
    }
```

It failed, of course. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Include the error, or say how it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cannot convert value "data.csv" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At line:5 char:1
+ Rename-Item $file.name ($lotId + $file.name)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger
```

Is the error you were most likely getting was because of this line

```
Rename-Item $file.name ($lotId + $file.name)
```

`$lotid` is an integer and you were trying to perform a mathematical operation with a string which is not possible where file names are concerened. The *simplest thing* to do to make this work is place the variable in quotes so that it is only treated as a string during the rename.

```
Rename-Item $file.name ("$lotId" + $file.name)
```

---

Since you know the path you are working on I would shy away from relying on the current path being the working path. Something like this would also do what you want. Remove `-WhatIf` when you are done your testing.

```
$lotId = 1
$path =  "D:\Temp\New folder"
Get-ChildItem $path | Foreach-object{
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ("{0}{1}" -f $lotId++,$_.Name) -WhatIf
}
```

We update `$lotId++` during each loop pass so there is no need for a separate line to increase that. There are other snippets that would work for sure. This is the first one I did that didn't do anything crazy.