# Rename .pdf files in powershell using regex

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, rename

My payslips are downloaded from work to my laptop as pdf files with the name

> PaySlip 04_06_2019 - 08_06_2019

with the date in ddmmyyyy format

I am trying to rename them to sort better

> PaySlip20190604-20190608

I'm trying to cobble together bits and pieces and have found using regex that I can convert the filename to the format I want if I enter it as text. The code for that is below

```
'PaySlip 04_06_2019 - 08_06_2019.pdf' -replace 
'.+(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{4}) - (\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{4}).pdf', 
'Payslip$3$2$1-$6$5$4'
```

But can't find a way to use it with get-childitem and rename-item to actually rename the files. I've tried adding the above code into gci in various different trial and error ways but none have worked.

Does anyone know where I have gone wrong, or in what way I need to use the code I typed to functionally rename files?

Thanks

SOLUTION:

```
Get-ChildItem *.pdf | 
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace 
'.+(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{4}) - (\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{4}).pdf', 
'Payslip$3$2$1-$6$5$4.pdf' }
```

Comment: you can post that solution as an Answer. [*grin*] not only that, but you can accept it and get reputation points.

Comment: Please have a look at: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [Etiquette for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename file names incrementally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36741224/rename-file-names-incrementally) or [Rename file with Filename Date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40176656/1701026)

Comment: @Lee_Dailey genius, ive done that now, cheers

Comment: @AlexRussell - you can also mark it as Accepted [*grin*] ... the reputation points will help you. plus, you likely otta work thru the S-O intro since that is worth 100 rep points [i think].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
Get-ChildItem *.pdf | 
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace 
'.+(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{4}) - (\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{4}).pdf', 
'Payslip$3$2$1-$6$5$4.pdf' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope thats what you wanted:

```
#$path = "Path to your DPFs Folder"
$path = "c:\MyPDFs"

$AllPDFs = Get-ChildItem $path
foreach($pdf in $AllPDFs)
{
    cd $path
    $Newpdf = $pdf -replace '[\s+*_]',''
    Rename-Item $pdf -NewName $Newpdf
}
```

PaySlip 04_06_2019 - 08_06_2019

PaySlip04062019-08062019

Best Regards.